# How to get the name of the device printed with adb devices?

Tags: android, shell, device, adb

When I type

```
adb devices
```

in the console, then it prints this:

```
List of devices attached 
SH16BV815282    device
```

How do I programmatically get the `SH16BV815282`, if it possible at all?

I want to get that value by android application at run time. Where this value is actually stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [`Build.SERIAL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL). However, it's only available on Android 2.3+.

Comment: so under 2.3 I cant read this ?, is there some ACL (like for fragments) that can delegate the reading of this value ?

Comment: No, at least not in a very hackish way. For the hackish way refer to the second link in **Yashwanth Kumar**'s answer.

Comment: adb devices and Build.SERIAL give very differnt results on my galaxy tab 10.1 with android 3.2

Comment: Build.SERIAL gives "unknown" on Galaxy S (OS version 2.3.3).

Answer (score 0):

I am using blow code for geting name of the device.

GUIStatics.deviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;